Understanding invertible matrices.
Every $n \times n$ matrix I've row reduced has ended up being identity. I searched in a textbook for why, and it said that all $n \times n$ matrices that are invertible row reduce to the identity matrix. But, it also said that every matrix has a unique reduced echelon form?
Is the identity the unique reduced echelon form? And a further question -- when row reducing, I've been told that we preserve the information in the vectors. That's precisely what makes reducing so great, it's easy to see solutions in that form. However, I'm clearly losing a lot of information when I row reduce to identity?
Can anyone provide any additional explanation? Thank you!

You might be misunderstanding what they mean by a "unique reduced echelon form". Does this post help?

Note that it's not that hard to find a matrix in reduced row echelon form that is not the identity.  For instance, $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,}  $$ which is not the identity...

You don't lose any information when reducing to reduced row echelon form because the process is reversible. The identity matrix is the preferred basis but the spans of both matrices are the same and the choice of basis is arbitrary.

The statement 'every matrix has a unique reduced echelon form' means that a matrix $M$ cannot have two matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ that are both reduced row echelon forms of $M$. So what you said is not in opposition with the claim.
It is indeed correct because you're only looking at invertible matrices. Every invertible matrix is full rank, and the unique RREF of any full rank matrix is the identity matrix. To see why, consider how you get a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors and impose the condition due to being RREF:

The first non-zero entry in each row (the pivot) is $1$.
All entries in the same column as a pivot are $0$.
Pivots in a row are strictly to the right of the last seen pivot in a preceding row.


Not every square matrix reduces to the identity. Some answers and comments have clarified that.
The criteria for when a matrix reduces to the identity can be expressed in a number of ways (invertible matrices, determinants, columns being linearly independent, etc.). No matter which criterion you choose, the basic principle you are noticing in your ad hoc calculations is that a randomly chosen square matrix will have RREF given by the identity, even if not every matrix has RREF the identity.
More precisely -- to avoid nitpickers -- the space of matrices with RREF not equal to I has codimension 1 in the space of all matrices (as an geometric space) and so unless you are unlucky to land in the smaller space of singular matrices, you will just keep row reducing to I all day long.
